# How to monitor Microsoft Graph usage?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft Graph has [throttling limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling-limits#outlook-service-limits) which is understandable.

However, is there a way to monitor our usage of Microsoft Graph to anticipate if we might be close to these limits?

Answer (score 0):

The feature to monitor Microsoft Graph usage is not available at the moment, if you want to raise a feature request for it [Feature request](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform).